# Pass output of shell command to inside .env file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have a .env file for a php application. The contents are similar to this:

```
#define env
#dev,stage,prod
env=stage

http="https://"

#define debug
debug=true
debug_level=2

#db
mysql_host=staging-rds.cvexrtrtr1.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
mysql_port=3306
mysql_username=dev
mysql_password="existing!secret"
```

I want to store the secret for mysql_password in the AWS paramater store. The goal is to not have the value `existing!secret` exposed to env variables or to anyone accessing the machine,
Basically I want the output of a bash command similar to the one below, to be passed on directly inside the .env file:

```
export DB_PASSWORD=$(aws ssm get-parameter \
  --name "secret-for-the-password" \
  --with-decryption \
  | jq -r '.Parameter.Value')
```

Is it fundamentally possible to pass the output of this command to the .env file? Output should be something similar to:

```
#define env
#dev,stage,prod
env=stage

http="https://"

#define debug
debug=true
debug_level=2

#db
mysql_host=staging-rds.cvexrtrtr1.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
mysql_port=3306
mysql_username=dev
mysql_password="$(aws ssm get-parameter \
  --name "secret-for-the-password" \
  --with-decryption \
  | jq -r '.Parameter.Value')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the secret stored as an environment variable would seem like a better option but if this fits your needs better, you could use `exec` to run the bash code, for example:

```
<?php

$mysql_password = "aws ssm get-parameter \
--name \"secret-for-the-password\" \
--with-decryption \
| jq -r '.Parameter.Value'";

$retval = exec($mysql_password);

echo $retval;
```

Comment: ok. So in my .env file, what value should I mention for `mysql_password=`? Basically how do I tie this PHP code back to my .env file?

Comment: mysql_password = "aws ssm get-parameter \
--name \"secret-for-the-password\" \
--with-decryption \
| jq -r '.Parameter.Value'";

Comment: ok thanks. Let me try it out. I wasn't sure if we can directly pass a shell command in a `.env`